# autoloading issue in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I put `password.php` file in `components` folder. In **phpStorm** existing functions in the `password.php` are shown well(auto-completion), but when running encountered with this:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in . . .\protected\controllers\SiteController.php on line 129`

What's the reason?

main.php

```
...
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii only autoloads **classes** if file name is same as class name and and if class definition file is in import path. For file containing bundle of functions you have to `include` (or `require`) it manually.
To include you could use `dirname(__FILE__)` (php 5.2) or `__DIR__` (php 5.3+) to get path to current file, and then append relative path to your file and file name. You could put this in `index.php`, something like that:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../protected/components/password.php';
```

or more simply if you have php 5.3+:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../protected/components/password.php';
```